# Using new operator with return of a javascript function returns odd scope

Tags: javascript, new-operator

Im trying to understand why new runs against the function rather than the return of the function in the example `y =`:

```
function returnFunction(){ return function blah(str){ this.x = str; return this;}}

y = new returnFunction()("blah")
// output: Window {x: "blah"; top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, ....}
x = new (returnFunction())("blah")
// output: blah {x: "blah"}

z = new function blah(){return this;}()
// output: blah {}

zz = new function(){return this;}() //note the missing function name
// output: Object {}

b = new function blib(str){this.x = str; return this}
// blib {x: undefined}
bb = new function blib(str){this.x = str; return this}("blah")
// blib {x: "blah"}
c = new function blib(){this.x = "blah"; return this}
// blib {x: "blah"}
```

So in the case of y *new* creates a copy of the `returnFunction` then invokes it

```
y = (new returnFunction())()
```

And by invoking an anonymous function we have no `this` so it defaults to `Window`.

In the case of `x`, by wrapping it in the parens (`returnFunction` is invoked returning a the `blah` function) and then `blah` is invoked by the new operator setting `this` to a new object.

It seems odd that I have to wrap `new (returnFunction())` to make it execute in the right order.

Could someone explain to me the underlying execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` has higher precedence than the invocation parens `()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because of operator precedence. `new` has higher precedence than the function call. Wrapping your function call in parenthesis changes the order of evaluation.

See the precedence table on MDN for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence